# What are the use cases for sbt-cross-building in sbt 0.13?

Tags: scala, sbt

[With the recent issue reported against sbt-cross-building](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-cross-building/issues/28) (that errors when `.value` macro is used for attributes), I wonder what are the use cases for the plugin for sbt 0.13.2 and on? Isn't the built-in `crossScalaVersions` facility enough (as described in [Cross-building](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Cross-Build.html))?

What are the use cases that necessitate the existence of the sbt-cross-building plugin in sbt 0.13 and on?

Comment: Never used it. But I think `crossScalaVersions` lets you build projects for multiple Scala version, while sbt-cross-building lets you build plugins for multiple sbt versions? These seem like entirely different things. (And I guess some people are still on 0.12.x, so there's a need to release plugins for both 0.12 and 0.13.)

Comment: That reflects my sentiments. I wonder if there's a "blessed" solution for the recent releases of sbt since the plugin does so much sbt re-wiring/writting that causes migrating to 0.13 so much pain.

Comment: @SethTisue You are right - it is a plugin for building plugins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sbt-cross-building is like a musician's music — a plugin author's plugin. Since sbt now retains binary compatibility in between minor releases, there's now less demand for sbt-cross-building, but it used to be a regular ritual among the sbt plugin authors to republish every time sbt release comes out. So when this plugin came out, it used to be my favorite plugin of all time.

There was a talk even about merging the plugin into the sbt mothership, but instead previous owners of sbt came up with a mechanism to cross publish sbt 0.13 plugins from [sbt 0.12.4](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/simple-build-tool/wgMu0h6oxEs/cFFVZYlYfb8J):

```
sbtVersion in Global := "0.13.0-RC1" 

scalaVersion in Global := "2.10.2"
```

This worked well enough that sbt-cross-publishing kind of missed the wave during 0.12 to 0.13 jump. One of the neat features on sbt-cross-publishing is that you can create a custom Scala source directories that are used for specific sbt versions. This allowed a single code base of plugins to be used even when the source-level compatibility was broken from the sbt side.

The concept of cross building across sbt versions is useful one just like cross building across Scala versions. At the same time, partially due to the stasis during the minor releases, the major release jump is big enough that many of the plugins I maintain required cutting a new version to take advantage of new Scala version, library, DSL syntax etc.

Comment: Thanks Eugene! I think with Scala 2.11 and sbt 0.13.2 out the plugin's use is going to be diminishing as the code doesn't seem to be heavily updated.